# How to unpad PKCS#7 / PKCS#5 padding?

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, padding

I would like to for help with using the [cryptography.hazmat.primitives.padding.PKCS7](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/padding/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.padding.PKCS7) Python class.

After decryption I'm getting the string `453947000000197708080808`, when the plaintext *should* be `4539470000001977`. According to our development team, the plaintext should be padded with PKCS#5 padding. So I searched for this class, but could not get it to work.

I could also do it manually by taking the last 2 digits, converting them to an integer, multiplying it by 2 and cutting the string from right by that number. However, I would prefer to do the unpadding using functions from the same package that I used for decryption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characters that you are seeing are a hexadecimal *representation* of the binary bytes. What you have are 12 bytes with the given value, ending with four bytes valued 8. There are however some things that are seriously wrong with that output:

- for PKCS#7 padding, which you would expect, the result should be eight bytes valued `08` or four bytes valued `04`;
- for a 8 or 16 byte block cipher you would expect 16 bytes as result;

I'm therefore expecting that you left out 4 bytes of the result. Otherwise the decryption would not have succeeded: the input for CBC or ECB decryption *has* to be a multiple of eight or 16 bytes, or an error should be generated.

Generally the unpadding doesn't have to be performed separately. The padding is usually *configured* for the ECB or CBC modes of operation. And generally, the PKCS#7 unpadding is the default for ECB and CBC (e.g. in Java and OpenSSL).

---

In case you are wondering, I've described the differences between PKCS#5 and PKCS#7 padding [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9043/1172) on [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hi Maarten, first of all thank you for a prompt answer. Its possible that I did something wrong. I'll come to you tomorrow as I speek to Security dev. Its very likely I did something wrong during decryption

Comment: If the PKCS#7 padding is configured already then you're likely ignoring the return value of the `finalOperation` method (whatever that is called) and including a full buffer size or similar. You may need just to include `x` bytes of the buffer, where x is returned as result value. Good luck.

Comment: Maarten, you were 100% right. I did a mistake during copy/paste because I checked the logs and I see exact number of padded bytes with number mentioned in padding "'45394700000019770808080808080808'" I cut unintentionally last 4 bytes. This is the reason why I could not properly parse it :( Thank you